# Detect mobile device rotation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, sensors

I am searching for a jQuery-plugin or Javascript-library that detects the rotation of a device in degrees, not just orientation, using the G-sensor. I know it can be done - check http://wagerfield.github.io/parallax/ - but I haven't managed to find something like this yet.

It would be great if it created a kind of global that updates realtime.

Thanks!

Comment: See this link may be useful.1)http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/jquery4u-parallax-demo/ and if you are working with phonegap 2)http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_compass_compass.md.html#Compass

Answer (score 6):

you can use jquery mobile lib orientationchange event.

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(event){
    var x = event.beta,  // -180 to 180
        y = event.gamma, // -90 to 90
        z = event.alpha; // 0 to 360
});
```

without jQuery:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(event){
    var x = event.beta,  // -180 to 180
        y = event.gamma, // -90 to 90
        z = event.alpha; // 0 to 360
});
```

also try this..

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event){
    });
}
```

Comment: I made a jsfiddle of it, http://jsfiddle.net/ywYPR/1/, but it didn't do the trick on my device. I wonder why.