# Mobile Tilt - Change Css

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, orientation

I was wondering how to change the CSS of my mobile application when a user tilts his phone (not switching from portrait to landscape) forward, backward, left, right.

Something like

```
<H1>This is my header</H1>

<script>

$('.tiltleft(function() {
    $('H1').AddClass('TiltedLeft');
});

$('.tiltright(function() {
    $('H1').AddClass('TiltedRight');
});

</script>
```

Comment: Probably there is a thread on this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060833/detect-mobile-device-rotation-with-jquery

Comment: Well I wasn't exactly how I wanted it there, but I found something similar:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation

I worked a bit on it and this is the result, which has two elements moving when tilted, as I'm no expert at this the only thing I can't seem to do is have one move in the opposite direction...

https://jsfiddle.net/ef4v2k7e/12/